# Understanfing the derivative of inverse functions.

Tags: limits, derivatives, notation, implicit-differentiation, inverse-function

If  $\,\,y=f^{-1}(x)$,

Then $x=f(y)$.

So $\,\,\frac{dx}{dy}=f'(x)$,

And $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{f'(x)}$.

Using the principle of differentiating by first principles,

Then $$\frac{dx}{dy}=\lim_{h\to 0}\,\,\frac{x(y+h)-x(y)}{h},$$

And, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{h \to 0}\,\,\frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}{h}.$$

Does this mean that, $$\begin{equation}\lim_{h\to 0}\,\,\frac{x(y+h)-x(y)}{h}=\left[ \lim_{h \to 0}\,\,\frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}{h} \right] ^{-1} \end{equation},\qquad(1)$$

Or $$\lim_{h\to 0}\,\,\frac{x(y+h)-x(y)}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0}\,\,\left[\frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}{h} \right] ^{-1}?\qquad(2)$$

Or do both statements $(1)$ and $(2)$ mean essentially the same thing?

Comment: They do not mean the same thing

Comment: @Alessandro Blasetti, okay, which statement would be more appropriate to write?

Comment: I believe you should pay attention when considering the inverse of derivative, $\frac {dx}{dy}$ is not properly a fraction in the usual sense